# When data post to django api, ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] occur

Tags: python, django, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm recently learning how to use django as backend, and let react redux handle frontend. But when I try to implement login function in frontend, and post data to api, ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] occurs.

I used django's User model to create user, and used rest_framework to create API for login. Then, using react with redux as frontend. When user login, it will trigger reducer to implement a login action with axios.post, but the serverside keeps showing errors. When I just login on API view page, it works fine. So I think the problem is with frontend, but I couldn't figure it out.

my API for login

```py
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user,
            context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })
```

my redux action to login

```
export const login = (username, password) => dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers : {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    const body = {
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password
    }

    axios.post("/api/auth/login", body, config)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAIL
            })
        });
};
```

And in my Login.js Component

```
    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault;
        console.log(this.state.username, this.state.password);
        this.props.login(this.state.username, this.state.password);
    };
```

I use onSubmit to trigger event when user hit login button. I include consolo.log to check whether the data get correctly, and it works fine too.

When I check on Redux devTool on Chrome, neither LOGIN_SUCCESS nor LOGIN_FAIL been dispatched. And base on serverside's HTTP 200, I think the problem is not on backend. Somehow, when post succeeds​, the frontend can't receive the result.

```
[03/Aug/2019 19:20:40] "POST /api/auth/login HTTP/1.1" 200 139
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 58167)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/kyle/Desktop/Todo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/kyle/Desktop/Todo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Update :
My url pattern in user

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/auth', include('knox.urls')),
    path('api/auth/user', UserAPIView.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/register', RegisterAPIView.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/login', LoginAPIView.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/logout', KnoxViews.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout')
]
```

Comment: It seems correctly received to your server and cannot find where to go,  can you show your `urls.py`, something wrong with it.

Comment: I updated the urls.py of user api. I use catch-all urlpattern in root url, so when no url match the backend's pattern, it will just let frontend handle it.

Comment: create another `urls.py` in `knox` (I think you already did it) and add `path('/login', LoginAPIView.as_view()),` into it. Anything after `api/auth` should goes to `knox.urls` and there is no pattern match for `api/auth/login` in your `knox.urls`. Please try and let me know! Did you get it what I'm saying?

Comment: I understand, I tried to modify all the urlpatther that goes after "api/auth/" to avoid conflic. But it still won't work. I think the problem is on frontend, because when I used Postman to post data to "api/auth/login", it works.

Comment: For some reason, when I login in frontend, the url will immediately change to "/login?username=XXX&password=XXX" pattern. Will it be a chance that this cause the problem? Because I don't really know why the url will change automatically, I didn't setup this action.

Comment: I found the answer ,thank you for helping me. Turns out, I made a stupid mistake, I called e.preventDefault() in a wrong way.

Comment: ohhhhh, then it's not `django` side, wow. I'll keep it mind, thank you too!